# Dianthus, please identify the species... Dianthus barbatus or chinensis? Or some other?

Tags: identification, flowers, leaves

Dianthus, please identify the species... Dianthus barbatus or chinensis? Or some other?

[image: Flowers]
[image: Leaves]

Answer (score 1):

Dianthus chinensis X barbatus...so kind of BOTH.  The common name is even worse; Floral lace lilac dianthus.  My goodness.  There must be a way to name just this dark mauve/pink with white borders more distinctly...but this is its name.

Comment: You don't think a Dianthus deltoides variety, similar to Bedazzled?

Comment: If it is Dainthus chinensis x barbatus, the X denotes a cross between the two - also listed as Dianthus F1 Interspecific by the geneticists/breeders

Comment: They hybridize freely anyhoo.  I know that if I was in my Botany ID class with a microscope and that wonderful Pacific Northwest Key, I could ID a flower down to variety but not much farther. Gosh, these people need to keep a tag from the nursery they get these plants from, as this is pretty tough to do.  You, Bamboo, are excellent with IDing flowers.  Especially your ID's with roses...omg.  Yup Interspecific BY THE BREEDERS!!  Who better to ID via sight?  And they can't do it 100%.  Grins!!

Comment: There are so many newly bred varieties of Dianthus which have appeared in the last five years or so, its next to impossible to keep up with ID

Comment: That is why I am amazed you can ID flowers...especially roses!  Arghhhh.

Comment: Well I can't ID  them all, only some!